# how to make "Creme Caramel" coffee flavored?

Tags: baking, coffee, caramel

I tried it Vietnam 3 years ago.

I prefer the Vietnamese version, there they made it with coffee flavored liquid on top[image]

Thanks!

Comment: After @Johanna's edit, I think the question is perfectly reasonable, and doesn't need a recipe to answer it - I've linked to one only for reference, and would prefer to refer to a recipe for plain creme caramel that  the OP is already happy with

Comment: @AMtwo If Seasoned Advice SE really doesn't allow recipe requests, I suggest it should.

What useful difference could anyone see between asking for help or modifications with an extant recipe, and asking for a recipe in the first place?

Is anyone seriously suggesting none of us can make up bogus recipes that don't do what we want, then ask for help or modifications that can't but lure innocent members into Posting workable recipes? Further, I just re-read the Help section and saw no reference at all to recipes, so where should anyone look for clarity?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin recipe requests are viewed as too subjective to be on-topic, as there are _many_ variations for a recipe and the "best" or "right" recipe can't be considered definitively answered in a Q&A format. [This FAQ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has more detail. It may be a fine distinction, but having a recipe for a starting point for variation with a specific goal is less subjective. If you have questions in that regard, I suggest asking on [meta](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/), rather than continuing conversation here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question suggests you want to make the caramel syrup part coffee-flavoured.  I'd simply replace the water used in making that with espresso (if you can get real espresso).  You don't need much so if you can't make it at home, perhaps get a takeaway from a coffee bar. If you can't get real espresso, something close like aeropress espresso  or moka (stove-top espresso), in both cases using a lot of coffee to the amount of water.  Instant espresso powder is a last resort, or for reinforcing the flavour if it turns out too weak.

If you want to make the custard part coffee flavoured, I've had success in the past infused hot milk with ground coffee before filtering.  I was going for very strongly flavoured to make a latte buttercream, but you wouldn't need to.  Instead as the milk starts to warm, stir in ground coffee, continue heating, then filter (through a coffee filter paper, which you can put in a sieve for a one-off if you don't have a filter cone) before you add it to the egg.   Again, avoid instant coffee.  Strength will be hard to get right.  My best guess would be something like a tablespoon of ground coffee to 250ml of milk, but I'd suggest aiming for subtle rather than overpowering on the first attempt, and use a little less.

I referred to [this recipe](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/creme-caramel); you may need to modify my steps slightly if yours works differently.

Answer (score 2):

In Vietnamese, it's called *bánh flan*. The coffee variation of bánh flan is called *bánh flan cà phê*.

To add coffee flavor, there are several ways:

1. You make plain black coffee with a coffee filter. Filtered coffee is cooked with sugar in a pan until it's thicker (caramelized).
2. You make plain black coffee with a coffee filter. Sugar is caramelized in a pan separately.
3. You mix coffee grounds/ instant coffee with hot water.

I believe the first or second way is more proper, and the last way is invented by home cooks for convenient purpose.